# Is the gas price static in ethereum?

Tags: transactions, gas, accounts, miner

From what I understand, as a miner, I can set whatever gas price I want. So for my test private ethereum network I set, in geth, for my miner a gas price of zero.

I tried doing a transaction from an account with a balance of 0 but I got an error that the account balance is too low.

So why does it fail? Is the gas price somehow adjusted automatically by geth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See chapter 6.2 of the [yellow paper](http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf). In short, the gas value has to fulfill a mathematical relationship that implies a value greater than 0.

Comment: Then why am I allowed to set price to 0 and not get an error ? And if in the back the gas price is not set to zero then to what value is it set ?

Comment: You can set the price to 0 and not get an error because the relationship does not have to hold yet. It's only when you make the transaction that the it has to hold.